# Can JFrog Xray scan binaries during a Jenkins job with artifacts from Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jfrog-xray

I have quite a few applications with source and binary code in Bitbucket repositories.  Jenkins is my CI/CD platform which is locally installed.  For the most part, Jenkins jobs simply pull binary files from the Bitbucket repo and deploy to target hosts (Windows). Our devs generally execute builds locally and push the source and binary files (.Net) to the repos.  A few projects are npm or ant/maven builds.  My CISO would like to integrate vulnerability scanning using JFrog Xray into the CI process.  Therefore, I have several questions.

1. Will JFrog/Xray perform a scan as a build step without switching to Artifactory for version control?
2. Which version of JFrog/Xray do I need?  Will the free version work?
3. Do I need to install JFrog/Xray locally, or can I use a hosted version?
4. Is there any documentation for my use case?  I've reviewed JFrog's documentation, but most related to using Artifactory.
5. Is there an alternative to JFrog/Xray that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

1. Nope, Xray without Artifactory never works
2. Artifactory does have the OSS version for Maven projects which is free that will be onprem but no Xray onprem, though you can refer to this [link](https://jfrog.com/start-free/) to create a free JFrog platform with Artifactory and Xray.
3. For local version which is onprem environment licensing is needed and for cloud you can go with the free versions available.
4. As you referred documents, Artifactory is needed for Xray to work.

Comment: I should clarify a little in that I would not switch to Artifactory for repo management.  There was mention in documentation that Xray would work without switching to Artifactory repos by .